# CSS solution for dynamic number of columns in a single row

Tags: html, css, dynamic-columns

i've been struggling all day with this...

i'm try to skin an existing control with CSS, for reasons of product QA, i dont want to edit the code that generates the tabs.

the control is a tabs control that is dynamically generated HTML...

i want all the tabs in a single row... which is fine... but when it reaches the edge of the container... i want all the child tabs to squash up and hide or ellipsis any text over flow.

what i've got -

```
----------------------------------------
|tab1       |tab2       |tab        |tab   <-  container edge with tab 4 hidden.
```

what i want -

```
|tab1    |tab2   |tab 3  |tab 4  |tab x |
```

or -

```
|ta...|ta...|ta...|ta...|ta...|ta...|ta...          you get the idea...?
```

the html is spans in a div... like snakes on a plane...

```
<div>
   <span>tab1</span>
   <span>tab2</span>
         ...
   <span>tabx</span>
</div>
```

any hope?

thanks

edit: gotta work in IE7 :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8S9L/1/)- it should solve everything you've asked for

HTML

```
<div>
   <span>tab1</span>
   <span>tab2</span>
   <span>tabx</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 div {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 0 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: that is pretty much it, however the code generates divs and spans... they have id's and stuff , is there a way to style them into <ul> and <li>? perhaps with something like :before and content??  (sorry if this is a bit naive, i've only been at this a week )

Comment: Sure, sorry, my bad for replying quickly- I've updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/L8S9L/1/

Comment: damn you are boss dude... your solutions looks so much like what i was trying... why the hell didnt mine work?!! :) thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

simple add this CSS :

```
    div{width:100%}
   div > span {
                float:left;
                width:40px; //customise width as per your purpose, can be in %ge too!
                overflow:hidden;  //hides extra text
                white-space:nowrap  //avoid getting on new line
              }
```

fix width will give the area to limit to, hope this helps!! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/43fu9/ - am i missing something? (it wraps when you squash the window up)

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say here....i thought (http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/43fu9/2/) this is what  you wanted!! :)